# set the state through a function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am checking a condition and if that condition holds true then through function a want to change the state. i tries but i console it is still showing false only. it will be really helpful if you suggest good way to to it,

```
this.state = {
popUpStatus:false,
}

handlePopUp = () => {
    this.setState({
      popUpStatus: true,
    });
  }

if(a > 100){
    this.handlePopUp;
    console.log(popUpStatus)l // false
}
```

Comment: because your if statement is not executed. you need to add the `if...` statement inside a function and call that function when the component loads or add the `if..` logic inside life cycle hooks.

Answer (score 2):

`this.setState()` is an asynchronous call. Therefore, You should not check `this.state.popUpStat` value right after calling `this.setState()`.

The correct way to do so is passing a callback function as a second parameter in `this.setState()` call like

```
    this.setState({
      popUpStatus: true,
    },()=>console.log(this.state.popUpStatus))
```

Comment: it is still false

Comment: You need to bind `this.handlePopUp` with `this` inside `constructor()` method
Try  -> `this.handlePopUp = this.handlePopUp.bind(this)`
Also, make sure you are declaring `this.state` inside `constructor()` method

Answer (score 0):

You have to display `this.state.popUpStatus`

Replace `console.log(popUpStatus)` with `console.log(this.state.popUpStatus)`

Comment: its still giving false,

Comment: Try this: setTimeout(function(){ console.log(this.state.popUpStatus); }, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

`setState` function does not update the state immediately. It just enqueues the changes. `popUpStatus` will have a different value once the component is re-rendered.

*"`setState()` enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component....."*

You can read more on `setState` here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

To test it, you can log it in your render function, and check how it updates.

Comment: is there any alternate to get the result

Comment: I am not sure why you need to get the result of a setState immediately after you have set it. But whatever you have there, should print `false` then prints `true` after it re-renders (which it must in the background ). Maybe you can share your work to understand exactly what you need. May me you shouldn't be using setState

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this:

```
this.handlePopUp();
console.log(this.state.popUpStatus);
```

But consider that setState is async function so you have to do this:

```
this.setState({
  popUpStatus: true,
}, ()=> { console.log(this.state.popUpStatus); });
```

Perhaps with hooks should be better:

```
useEffect(()=> { setPopUpStatus(a>100); }, [a])
```

Comment: it is still giving false